# C++: Passing a non moveable functor to a std::function

Tags: c++, std-function

How can one pass a non moveable object to a std::function? One easy enough alternative is passing a `std::reference_wrapper` which would create the need for the lifecycle of function be dependant on the object. Example code follows to explain the issue better.

```cpp
class Player {
  std::atomic_int runs {0};
  std::string name;

public:
  Player(std::string&& name) : name(std::move(name)) {}  //...
  void inc() { ++runs;}
};

class PlayerStats {
  std::array<std::unique_ptr<Player>,2> players;
public:
  PlayerStats() {
    for(int i = 0; i<2 ; i++)
      players[i] = std::unique_ptr<Player>(new Player{"player"+std::to_string(i)});
  }
  Player* const operator() (int index) const {
    return players[index].get();
  }
};

using player_total_f = std::function<Player* const(int index)>;

class GameStats {
  std::string game;
  std::string date;
  player_total_f f;

public:
  GameStats(std::string&& game, std::string&& date, player_total_f&& _f) :
    game(std::move(game)), date(std::move(date)), f(std::move(_f)) {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  PlayerStats st;
  //GameStats("game1","10.11",std::ref(st)); //this seems like the only possibility, no way to make GameStats own the functor
  return 0;
}
```

How can I set the function here to `PlayerStats`, given that it is non copyable, a std::ref seems to be like the only possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class F>
auto shared_function( F&& f ){
  auto spf=std::make_shared<std::decay_f<F>>(std::forward<F>(f));
  return [spf=std::move(spf)](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto){
    return (*pf)(decltype(args)(args)...);
  };
}
```

own it in a shared ptr.  Changes semantics a bit, but fixes it.

Or write your own non-copying std function.

Comment: What is _"ownnit inna shared ptr"_?

Comment: This is indeed nice, but is there a way to actually store the `shared_function` rv as a member or so?

Comment: ```template <typename F>
auto shared_function(F&& f){
  auto spf = std::make_shared<std::decay_t<F>>(std::forward<F>(f));
  return [spf = std::move(spf)](auto&& ...args) -> decltype(auto) {
           return (*spf)(decltype(args)(args)...);};
}
```

Comment: I think I have enough to proceed, I can modify this to just return the spf, and store the shared_ptr

Comment: @xworder Pass it to a std function of the appropriate signature.  It converts.